# How to access Spring Boot model with Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, vue.js

I am not sure how to access a model I create with my controller with Vue in my html. I know how to access model attributes with thymeleaf, but cannot find any info anywhere on how to access them with Vue. I would like to store the count value from the controller in the Vue data count I have below. I am using Vue within my template hosted with CDN, not as a separate project.

Here is my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/word")
public String searchSentence(@ModelAttribute WordSearch wordSearch, Model model) {
    int c = wordSearch.search();
    String count = String.valueOf(c);
    model.addAttribute("wordSearch", wordSearch);
    model.addAttribute("count", count);
    return "count";
}
```

Here is the count.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Count-Form</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Result</h1>
    <p th:text="'sentence: ' + ${wordSearch.sentence}" />
    <p th:text="'word: ' + ${wordSearch.word}" />
    <!--<p th:text="'count: ' + ${count}" /> -->
    <div id="count-text" style="display: none"> 
        <p th:text="${count}" /> 
    </div>
    <div id="app">
       {{count}}
    </div>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data() {
            return {
                count: ""
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.count = ???
        }
    })
</script>
    <a href="/greeting">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you just want to access a Spring Boot model in a Thymeleaf template without calling an API, take a look at [Accessing Spring MVC Model Objects in JavaScript](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-model-objects-js)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this blog to do what you desire. https://dev.to/brunodrugowick/spring-boot-vue-js-axios-and-thymeleaf-with-bootstrap-in-4-commits-2b0l. In this author explains how you can use Thymeleaf and VueJS together by adding VueJS dependency in pom.xml.

you need following dependency in your pom xml to use VueJS,

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>vue</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf is a server-side Java template engine, while Vue is a JS framework to build frontend layer. The best way to connect Spring with Vue would be by an API.
So you'll need to expose your data as a JSON, make a http call `vue app -> java api` and consume the response.

[Here](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-develop-and-build-vue-js-app-with-java-backend-4e9d72bb8ce5) you can find more details, how this works

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create a method returning ResponseBody, then you call this method in Vue (Axios is a good option!).
Example 1: function to get a String variable:

```
@GetMapping( "/getLanguage")
    @ResponseBody
    public String obtenerIdiomaActual() {
         return languageService.getLanguage();
    }
```

Then you'd need a method in your Vue app to read this value:

```
const vm = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            language: null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getLanguage() {
            axios.get(window.location.origin + '/getLanguage')
                .then(response => {
                    this.language = response.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.errorMessage = error.message;
                    console.error("There was an error!", error);
                });
        },
   
    mounted: function () {
        this.getLanguage();
    },
    watch: {
        idioma: function () {
            console.log("Language: " + this.language);
        }
    },
}).mount('#myApp')
```

You can use all kind of complex data: objects, arrays, dictionaries (maps)...

```
 @GetMapping( "/getComplexData")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, List<SpaceBean>> getMyComplexData() ...
```

And read the response easily with Vue:

```
<div  v-for="(spaceList, key) in datos">
    <p v-cloak><b>{{key}}</b></p>
        <table  class="display" style="width: 100%" v-cloak>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="space in spaceList">
                <td>{{space.alias}}</td>
                <td>{{space.descripcion}}</td>
                <td>{{space.url}}</td>
            </tr>
            ...
```

I hope this help a little!!